# NSSet takes just the last value from my for set

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data, nsset

i try to fetch the members from the entity "Teilnehmer" and then i want to save it to another entity "Buchungsteilnehmer" with a relationship to "buchung".

the problem is, that the nsset function saves just the last name and put it to a relationship with my entity "buchung". but i want to store all the members within the for statement into a relationship with "buchung".

Can you help me please

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Teilnehmer" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        [request setEntity:entity];

        NSArray *events = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];




        for (Teilnehmer *teil in events) {
         teilnehmer = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Buchungsteilnehmer" inManagedObjectContext:context];
            teilnehmer.name=teil.name;
            NSLog(@"Name der Teilnehmer lautet: %@",teil.name);
            NSError *error;
            if (![context save:&error]) 
            {
                NSLog(@"Fehler beim hinzufügen : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }

        }

        NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithObject:teilnehmer];    
        NSLog(@"SET: %@",set);
        buchung.buchungsteilnehmer=set;

        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) 
        {
            NSLog(@"Fehler beim hinzufügen : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create your set with only one object so how do you expect it to have more than one object ?

Change your code as follows :

```
  NSMutableSet *set = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];                

  for (Teilnehmer *teil in events) {
         teilnehmer = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Buchungsteilnehmer" inManagedObjectContext:context];
            teilnehmer.name=teil.name;
            NSLog(@"Name der Teilnehmer lautet: %@",teil.name);
            NSError *error;
            if (![context save:&error]) 
            {
                NSLog(@"Fehler beim hinzufügen : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            } else {
                [set addObject:teilnehmer];
            }

        }

   buchung.buchungsteilnehmer=set; // I assume you synthesized this member so it retains set
   [set release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a NSMutableSet before your for loop starts.  Call addObject on the set each time you insert a new entity.